# Traduction erronée ? « il est peu de ces âmes cadavéreuses devenues insensibles, hors leur intérêt, à tout ce qui est juste et bon. »

Tags: sens

La source primaire: Livre 4, *Émile* (1762) par Jean-Jacques Rousseau.

> [1.] Mais, quel que soit le nombre des méchants sur la terre, il est peu de ces âmes cadavéreuses devenues insensibles, hors leur intérêt, à tout ce qui est juste et bon.

Rencontré  la 1e fois p. 429 en bas à droite, [*Introducing Philosophy for Canadians: A Text with Integrated Readings*](https://www.amazon.ca/Introducing-Philosophy-Canadians-Integrated-Readings/dp/0195430964) (2011 1 ed).     [Traduction](http://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/rousseau-emile-or-education): (1921) by Barbara Foxley.

> [2.] There are many bad men in this world, but there are few of these dead souls, **alive** only to self-interest, and insensible to all that is right and good.

La traduction, est-elle juste en écrivant **alive** ? L'original n'utilise et n'implique point cet adjectif ?

Answer (score 2):

Rousseau emploie le mot « insensible » qu'on retrouve dans la traduction  *alive*. Traduction dans laquelle l'auteur a fait le choix de traduire une double négation par deux expressions positives, et donc au final le sens de la phrase est le même.

*insensible* (qui signifie  qui **n'** est **pas** sensible) → sensible  = **alive** <sup>1</sup>,

*hors leur intérêt* (qui signifie à ce qui **n'** est **pas** leur intérêt) → seulement à leur intérêt = only to self-interest.

Donc le sens de la phrase est bien le même. « Insensible » ayant été traduit par son contraire (sensible = *alive to*) et « hors leur intérêt » par une forme affirmative (dans leur intérêt = *only to self-interest*).

Pour répondre au commentaire de Stéphane Gimenez, pour moi l'auteur a décomposé l'expression de sensibilité différemment du texte de Rousseau : d'un côté il y a ce à quoi les « âmes cadavéreuses » sont sensibles (*alive to*) : leurs intérêts, et d'autre part ce à quoi elles sont insensibles : (*insensible*) : ce qui est juste et bon. Mais l'idée exprimée est bien la même.

<sup>1</sup> Le sens de *alive to* est conscient de / sensible à une idée.

Comment: *Insensible* à simplement été traduit par *insensible*. *Alive* n'est utilisé que pour remplacer l'incise « hors leur intéret » s'applicant à l'adjectif, qui passe mal en anglais dans ce cas. Du coup en utilisant un autre adjectif, la subtilité accordant que ces âmes puissent y être sensibles si c'est dans leur propre intéret est perdue dans la traduction. Mais c'est là un moindre mal.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Oui, en effet mais ça ne revient-il pas au même ? Tout ce qu'on peut ajouter c'est que l'auteur n'a pas voulu répéter « insensible » deux fois, car *alive to* est bien aussi rendu par *(in)sensible à*. Le texte original pour moi implique bien l'emploi du mot (in)sensible. Comme l'expliquerais-tu autrement ?